# Java ActionListener error <identifier>expected and illegal start of type

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I know these questions have been asked and I have searched for it on stackoverflow but my problem didn't get solved. I am getting error while setting actionlistener to a button but i am always getting errors:

```
Talk.java:25: error: <identifier> expected
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener());
                                        ^

Talk.java:25: error: illegal start of type    
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener());
                                         ^
```

THE CODE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
class Talk extends javax.swing.JFrame    {
public  void main(String args[]) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("LET'S TALK");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            JLabel textLabel=new JLabel("What's up.",SwingConstants.CENTER);
            textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(530,100));
            frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            JButton button=new JButton("OK");
            JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
            panel1.add(button);
            frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);}
            private class ActionListener {
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener());
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    final TextField tf=new TextField();
                    tf.setText("welcome");
                  }
             }
}
```

Comment: @JoeC Nope, and Don't Scream, we are here for you.

Comment: Same.... Same....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Try this

```
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      final TextField tf=new TextField();
      tf.setText("welcome");
    }

});
```

Edit: Your brackets are misplaced. Do it like this:

2nEdit: You should only call `frame.pack()` and `frame.setVisible(true)` after you add all your components to `panel`

```
class Talk extends javax.swing.JFrame    {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("LET'S TALK");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    JLabel textLabel=new JLabel("What's up.",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(530,100));
    frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JButton button=new JButton("OK");
    JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(8);

    panel1.add(button);
    panel1.add(textField);
    frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText("welcome");
        }
    });

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greggz for your help but the code still has error without @Override there were two errors but after Override there are 5 errors.And a error I am getting at the ); brace at the last that illegal start of type.

Comment: @AYUSHGUPTA Please post an Edit with all those specifications for us to understand them better

Comment: THANKS GREGGZ FOR YOUR HELP.THERE ARE NO MORE ERRORS BUT WHEN I PRESS THE BUTTON NOTHING HAPPENS(as per the code it should show "welcome").AND ONCE AGAIN THANKS FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: @AYUSHGUPTA That probably has to do with the fact that you're not adding the `tf ` to `panel`

Comment: @AYUSHGUPTA Check last edit. It's working now

Comment: As per you I have added tf to the panel and panel to the frame but still not showing anyting.

Comment: @AYUSHGUPTA Copy the last and entire code I posted. Your `tf` was invalid, I changed it

Comment: @AYUSHGUPTA Thanks! You can remove your email, I can't edit your comments lol. The next time you ask a question just tag me and I can try to answer. Good luck

Comment: @Gregzz can you tell me where to tag you?Do you mean in stackoverflow chat?If yes, then the problem is that the person with less than 20 rep are not allowed to chat.So please mail me your name to get your email id.

Answer (score -2):

Greggz is right.
You need to create an anonymous inner class of ActionListener implementing actionPerform(ActionEvent e) method and write your action code inside this method. This is the easiest way.

Or,  you can create a separate class implementing the ActionListener interface and override the actionPerform(ActionEvent e) method for your action code. Then just place  an object of that class here, 
button.addActionListener( hereObjectOfThatClass )